# Adding headers to existing table created in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I recently tried to create a table in tkinter. I luckily managed to find a pieces of code that works fine for me, however, I would need to add headers to this table. Do you have any suggestions how to incorporate it into the code I found here on forums?:

```
import tkinter as tk

class SimpleTableInput(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, rows, columns):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self._entry = {}
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns

        # register a command to use for validation
        vcmd = (self.register(self._validate), "%P")

        # create the table of widgets
        for row in range(self.rows):
            for column in range(self.columns):
                index = (row, column)
                e = tk.Entry(self, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)
                e.grid(row=row, column=column, stick="nsew")
                self._entry[index] = e
        # adjust column weights so they all expand equally
        for column in range(self.columns):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)
        # designate a final, empty row to fill up any extra space
        self.grid_rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)

    def get(self):
        '''Return a list of lists, containing the data in the table'''
        result = []
        for row in range(self.rows):
            current_row = []
            for column in range(self.columns):
                index = (row, column)
                current_row.append(self._entry[index].get())
            result.append(current_row)
        return result

    def _validate(self, P):
        '''Perform input validation. 

        Allow only an empty value, or a value that can be converted to a float
        '''
        if P.strip() == "":
            return True

        try:
            f = float(P)
        except ValueError:
            self.bell()
            return False
        return True

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.table = SimpleTableInput(self, 3, 4)
        self.submit = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.on_submit)
        self.table.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.submit.pack(side="bottom")

    def on_submit(self):
        print(self.table.get())


root = tk.Tk()
Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

I have tried the following but it clearly is not what I am after:

```
class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        names = ["header1", "header2", "header3"]
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=names)   
        self.table = SimpleTableInput(self, 3, 4)
        self.submit = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.on_submit)
        self.label.pack(side="top")
        self.table.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.submit.pack(side="bottom")
```

As stated below, I would like to have headers that dynamically appears above the table. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should not ask for examples without even showing an effort on your end. Have you tried something? If so what did you try. You may benefit from reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a label before the table will add the table header.

Update this portion of the code:

```
self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Table Header")
self.table = SimpleTableInput(self, 3, 4)
self.submit = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.on_submit)
self.label.pack(side="top")
self.table.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
self.submit.pack(side="bottom")
```

I have not repeated the given code again to let you think about it. Here is a reference [label in TKinter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm) you might find handy.

Comment: Great, Thanks! I am entirely new to coding in Python, that is the reason I did not write down any of my attempts. Hopefully, I will make it work.

Comment: I have progressed with your piece of code, however, what I am aiming for is to have a header for each column in that table, for e.g.: "column1" for the first column, "column2" for the second one, etc. I will keep trying to modify your code so it works, thanks.

Comment: If you think, the answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as accepted answer. Happy coding!